# Do SILK fibres let light pass through it?

Tags: structural-biology, light

The reason given by [Wikipedia](https://www.google.com/search?q=why%20are%20silk%20fibres%20lustrous&oq=why&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i59l2.2097j0j7&client=ms-android-oppo&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) for **silk fibres being lustrous** is that:

> Silk fibres have triangular prism-like structure, which allows them to **refract** the incoming light at different angles.

By my understanding, refraction takes place only when light enters another medium. (*This is only for reference*)

My question is: **Do silk fibres allow light to pass through them?**

Comment: If the question is not suitable for this site, I would like it to be transferred to the another site. Thanks!

Comment: Nobody bothers to reply.....

Comment: Patience, many of us are asleep or at work.

Comment: How is this about animal husbandry?

Comment: @MattDMo I beg your pardon, but you all are making fun of someone who is not as experienced and knowledgeable like you.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] or delete your question accordingly. MattDMo was pointing out a mistake in your post — constructive criticism is encouraged on this site. ——— Also, note that as written this question doesn't appear to be about biology, but instead about the optical properties (physics) of a biological material and so would seem to be off-topic for this site. Please consult the above links and [meta] for details.Thanks! 

Comment: @user100323 you tagged the question `animal-husbandry` and I simply inquired how this question and that tag were related. You are a member on enough other Stack Exchange sites that you must surely know how the tagging system works, so your plea of ignorance doesn't hold any water. The other comment was in reply to your complaining about no one commenting on or answering your post yet - not making fun at all. Here's a hint: when joining a new community, educate yourself about how it works instead of complaining about everything.

Comment: @user100323 as for your actual question, if the reason for silk fibers' being lustrous is that they diffract light, then *of course* light can pass through them. The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please see our [homework policy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) for more information. Additionally, as indicated above, this is not even about biology, it's about physics. Please read the [help] to learn more about this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, silk allows light through.

I did a google scholar search using terms:

optics of silk

Lots of articles, the article below measures a refractive index of about 1.54

Paywalled except abstract and figures.

Bucciarelli, V. Mulloni, D. Maniglio, R.K. Pal, V.K. Yadavalli, A. Motta, A. Quaranta,
A comparative study of the refractive index of silk protein thin films towards biomaterial based optical devices,
Optical Materials,
Volume 78,
2018,
Pages 407-414,
ISSN 0925-3467,
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.optmat.2018.02.058.

Found at:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0925346718301241